# Prepare UTF-8 string for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I got a string from an email subject

## input

```
=?UTF-8?B?RndkOiDwn5G+IEZpbmFsIEhvdXJzIHRvIFNhdmUg8J+Rvg==?=
```

## output (from convert_nin_acsii method)

```
Fwd:  Final Hours to Save
```

I want to insert it into mysql, but get an error

## error

```
2015-12-06 11:11 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBE F...' for column 'label' at ...
```

## code

I use this code to prepare the string for mysql

```
private function convert_non_ascii($string){
    $return = '';
    if(preg_match('/^=\?(iso-8859-1|utf-8)\?q\?/i', $string)){
        $return = str_replace('_',' ', mb_decode_mimeheader($string));
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/^(iso-8859-1\'\')(.*)$/i', $string, $matches)){
        $return = utf8_encode(rawurldecode($matches[2]));
    }
    else{
        $return = imap_utf8($string);
    }

    //  Fix: Remove all non UTF-8 characters if mail is not correctly encoded
    $return = mb_convert_encoding($return, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Just for clarity: are you sure your db connection is using UTF8 encoding? `SET NAMES utf8` or so?

Comment: yes.. all strings are utf-8 encoded both from and to the db server

Comment: so your `if-elseif-else` will got down the third option: I think you should use `utf8_decode(imap_utf8($string));` there

Comment: the output must be `utf-8` encoded..

Comment: @clarkk sorry i see, i misunderstood what you were trying to do with the regexs

Answer (score 0):

The column/table in MySQL must be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  MySQL's utf8 won't suffice for Emoji.

And you need `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

The utf8 hex for  is `F09F91BE` (4 bytes), and can be seen in the error message.

Comment: Is it possible tro strip all non two bytes characters.. I don't feel like changing mysql structure

Comment: @clarkk not really... you will end up stripping more then just emoji. Maybe just a regex that allows only ASCII chars? `preg_replace('|^[^a-zA-Z0-9\- ]*$|', '', $string)`, although, changing the MySQL structure would be best.